# How to access the field 'arg' of a function argument in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have a function:

```
def func(f: Any => WrappedDataset): WrappedDataset = {
 // I would like to do something like `val expr = f.arg.expr` here
}
```

There is no such field on 'f' called arg. But when I put a breakpoint inside of func I can see that the field I need "expr" is there at runtime.

[image: Inspecting the argument 'f' runtime]

Is there some way, perhaps using scala reflect, that I can take the value inside of one of the arg fields and save to a variable inside of func() ?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but there's no such thing as "arg" as far as the body of `func` is concerned. There's only a function that can be applied to an argument of the defined type, in your case `Any`.

Think of it like this: someone gifts you a pasta maker. Raw pasta goes in, spaghetti come out. When you're handed this pasta maker, you can't say "okay let me look at the raw pasta". For now, all you have is a pasta maker (function), and later once you obtain some raw pasta (value of type `Any`), you will be able to apply it.

If you need to know the argument in the body of `func()`, then you need to make it a parameter:

```
def func(f: Any => WrappedDataset, arg: Any): WrappedDataset
```

Comment: You pretty much got the question, the only caveat being I want the type WrappedDataset's value. As this code is being used as part of a library I need func to take 1 single function argument. I admittedly know very little about scala reflect and was under the impression this could be one solution. Perhaps the illusion of func() being called with one argument can be achieved with implicits.

Comment: I still think that you're not reasoning about this in a correct way. Method `func()` takes a single argument, and that argument is a function. It's not a function application - it's just a function definition. I don't know what you mean by `WrappedDataset`'s value, since there is no value at this point.  
  
It's like if I give you a function x => x + 1, and you then ask me "okay what's the value of the result". Which result?  I just gave you a function, we didn't apply it to any value.

Comment: In the rest of the `func()` body, there should be a point where `f` is applied to some value, e.g. `f("foo")` or `f(42)`. But just by looking at the `func` parameter `f`, you cannot reason about what the values of input/output are going to be. Same how seeing a function definition `x=>x+1` doesn't tell us anything about the values it will be producing in real life; all we know is the definition of the function ("add one to input").

Comment: Yes and no. In this func() there will not be an instance where f is applied to anything as what I am trying to do is create some syntactic sugar where the user passes a function argument but really what func needs to know about is the WrappedDataset value. 

Example usage will be: 

`x.func(_ => wrappedDataset)`

Comment: I am trying to find a way to do this. I thought scala reflect would be the appropriate way as when I put a breakpoint inside of func() there is evidence that the arg are available during runtime.

Comment: I don't know what `expr` is in this case, might be some Spark thing. But for sure you can't have access to the arg, because it is not available at runtime. Because it does not exist. Someone called `func()` at runtime with some function as param, and it caused `func` body code to be run, which triggered your breakpoint. But at that point, nobody has applied the function `f` yet. I might be failing at explaining this properly, but please let me assure you of one thing - having Scala code full of `Any` types and reflection inspections is a very bad idea in general anyway.

Comment: If the function `f` did have some argument applied to it, and produced a `WrappedDataset`, then it would not be a value of type `Any => WrappedDataset` any more. It would be a `WrappedDataset`. And such code wouldn't compile, because `func` wants a function, not a value of type `WrappedDataset`. And since we just proved that `f` wasn't applied, there can be no `WrappedDataset`. Sorry but this is about as far as I will go into this matter :) I would suggest some reading up on higher order functions, and I don't mean that in a rude / cocky / patronizing way, but I'm genuinely trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks for discussing, I will read more into that